# Java regex split with any number of asterisks

Tags: java, regex

I am learning regex (with [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)) and trying to figure out how to parse the following string `1***2` to give me `[1,2]` (without using a specific case for 3 asterisk). There can be any number of asterisks that I need to split as one delimiter, so I am looking for the * char followed by the * wildcard. The delimiters could be letters as well.

The output should only only be numbers so I use `^-^0-9` to split by everything else.

So far I have tried:

`input.split("[^-^0-9]");` // Gives me `[1, , ,2]`

`input.split("[^-^0-9\\**]");` // Gives me `[1***2]`

`input.split("[^-^0-9+\\**]");` // Gives me `[1***2]`

`\*` does not work as it is not recognized as a valid escape character.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `\*` is not an escape character in Java, but it IS in regex within Java.

Comment: There is no need for the second `^` in your character class `[]`, unless you are trying to _not_ split on the `^` character.

Comment: I removed it and it still passes all my test cases. Thanks! I am a regex noob.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for

```
input.split("[*]+");
```

This splits the string on one or more consecutive asterisks.

To allow other characters (e.g. letters) within delimiters, add them to the `[*]` [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: That worked! All together, `input.split("[^-^0-9]+[*]*"); ` fixed my issue to work with *** as well as other delimiters. Edit: Can't accept for 10 minutes D:

Answer (score 3):

If the delimiters could be letter..

you can use

```
\D+
```

OR

```
[^\d]+
```